# User input and Database: MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError

Tags: html, mysql, python-3.x, flask, user-input

my code allows me to display the results corresponding to the data provided by the user through a search in the database. But I have this error and I didn't manage to solve this error.

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: execute() first
```

here are the different parts
#home.html

```
<p class="article-content"> 
  <div class="form_form">
  <form class="form" method="post" action="/search">
    <label for="user_input"></label>
    <input id="user_input" name="user_input" type="text">
    <input type = "submit" value = "send">
  </form>  
</div>   
</p>
```

#search_results.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<article class="media content-section">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <h5><a class="mr-2" href="#">results for{{ user_input }}</a></h5>
    </div>
    <p class="article-content"><p>Family Name: </p>{{ results.name }}</p>
    <p class="article-content"><p>Family Description: </p>{{ results.description }}</p>
    <p class="article-content"><p>Address: {{ results.address }}</p>
    <p class="article-content"><p>Phone Number: {{ results.phone }}</p>
  </div>
</article>
 
 
<form>
  <input type="button" value="New Search" onclick="history.go(-1)">
</form>
 
{% endblock content %}
```

#routes.py

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
 
    cur = db.connection.cursor()
 
    if request.method == "POST":
         
        user_input = request.form["user_input"]  
 
        cur.execute = ("SELECT f.family_name, f.family_description, f.family_address, f.family_phone FROM Shop f WHERE f.family_address LIKE %s ORDER BY family_name", ( "%" + user_input + "%",))
 
        results = cur.fetchall()
         
        return render_template('search_results.html', user_input=user_input, results=results)
         
    else:
 
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Answer (score 0):

**This line:**

```
        cur.execute = ("SELECT f.family_name, f.family_description, f.family_address, f.family_phone FROM Shop f WHERE f.family_address LIKE %s ORDER BY family_name", ( "%" + user_input + "%",))
```

**should be:**

```
        cur.execute("SELECT f.family_name, f.family_description, f.family_address, f.family_phone FROM Shop f WHERE f.family_address LIKE %s ORDER BY family_name", ( "%" + user_input + "%",))
```